# I have installed chef-dk and started using berkshelf but berks upload failed

Tags: chef-infra, berkshelf, chefdk

I have installed chef client `12.0.3`, on top of it I have install chef-dk version `0.3.5` but why chef-dk is installing chef client version `Chef: 11.18.0.rc.1`

1. Unable to Upload cookbooks to chef server
2. berks shelf list is working but berks upload failed

Error:

```
E, [2015-01-08T04:58:36.707534 #22533] ERROR -- : Ridley::Errors::ClientError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
E, [2015-01-08T04:58:36.708931 #22533] ERROR -- : /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/responses.rb:29:in `value'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:92:in `value'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/proxies/sync_proxy.rb:33:in `method_missing'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/proxies/cell_proxy.rb:17:in `_send_

    There was an error connecting to the Chef Server
```

Answer (score 3):

It is failing the SSL verification process. Follow [these instructions](http://jtimberman.housepub.org/blog/2014/12/11/chef-12-fix-untrusted-self-sign-certs/) to fix it for knife. For berkshelf you can disable SSL verification in your `config.json` or you can set `$SSL_CERT_FILE` to the downloaded server certificate.

Comment: Ignore is set in ~/.berkshelf/config.json (or HOME%/.berkshelf/config.json)
`{     "ssl" : { "verify" : false }    }`

Answer (score 2):

This is a berks related issue.
You can cancel the ssl verify option in berks config file:

```
echo '{"ssl": { "verify": false }}' > ~/.berkshelf/config.json
```

Comment: Thank for sharing this. Did the job for me

Answer (score 1):

As I'm a big fan of fixing the error instead of fixing the symptom here is what you can do to be sure the SSL connection works with validation (with a little more detail than coderanger one):

1) Get the server certificate and add it to the cacert.pem file of chef-dk

`openssl s_client -showcerts -connect <YOUR_CHEF_SERVER>:443 </dev/null 2>/dev/null|openssl x509 -outform PEM >> /opt/chefdk/embedded/ssl/certs/cacert.pem`

2) set the env variables for ssl libs:

`export SSL_CERT_FILE=/opt/chefdk/embedded/ssl/certs/cacert.pem`

Retry your upload and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can also disable ssl checking on the command line:

```
berks upload --no-ssl-verify
```