# Enabling SSL for berk upload in WINDOWS

Tags: chef-infra, berkshelf, chefdk

Recently, I found I had a problem with berks upload and found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27833419/i-have-installed-chef-dk-and-started-using-berkshelf-but-berks-upload-failed) provided by [Tensibai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3627607/tensibai), it was for a *nix system, and I am hoping for a command that would address someone using windows to develop with chefdk. Specifically, how to make this:

openssl s_client -showcerts -connect :443 /dev/null|openssl x509 -outform PEM >> /opt/chefdk/embedded/ssl/certs/cacert.pem

Work under windows.

Answer (score 0):

`knife ssl fetch https://yourserver:443/` should dump the cert. Add it to C:\opscode\chefdk\embedded\ssl\certs\cacert.pem

Comment: Are you using the Berkshelf of ChefDK?

Comment: ChefDK, which install Berkshelf

chef-repo (master) $ berks --version
3.2.4