# How to properly configure berks to avoid certificate issues?

Tags: chef-infra, berkshelf

I'm using chefDK with the following versions:

```
Chef Development Kit Version: 0.17.17
chef-client version: 12.13.37
delivery version: master (f68e5c5804cd7d8a76c69b926fbb261e1070751b)
berks version: 4.3.5
kitchen version: 1.11.1
```

Chef connection to the server seems to work fine with knife as I can run all the commands correctly. But when I run the

> berks upload

command I get this error

```
Ridley::Errors::ClientError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed
```

I had this problem also with the knife command but I resolved it when I copied my certificate in the default path ~/.chef/trusted_certs/

I can solve the problem with the certificate setting the environment variable SSL_CERT_FILE pointing to the certificate file but I cannot use this permanently because if it is set I have another error running the command

> berks vendor

```
/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/httpclient-2.7.2/lib/httpclient/ssl_socket.rb:46:in `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (Faraday::SSLError)
```

So basically I have to continuously set and unset that variable in order to work properly, which as can you imagine is quite annoying.

How can I configure properly berkshelf to work?

Thanks,
Michele.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I have installed chef-dk and started using berkshelf but berks upload failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27833419/i-have-installed-chef-dk-and-started-using-berkshelf-but-berks-upload-failed)

Comment: See the answers in duplicate, mainly you'll have to paste your cert into the cacert.pm and set SSL_CERT_FILE to this cacert.pem to have both methods working.

Comment: It worked adding the cert to the file pointed by the second answer. I wasn't sure the two things was related. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately Berkshelf uses its own HTTP client layers so it doesn't (yet?) support Chef's `trusted_certs/` folder. This means you have to do things the old-school OpenSSL way with `$SSL_CERT_FILE` or `$SSL_CERT_DIR`. As Tensibai mentioned, you would need to build a new trust DB for OpenSSL one way or another. It's not a direct equivalence but I will mention for the record that the Policyfile tools do support `trusted_certs/`.

Comment: I added the certificate content to /opt/chefdk/embedded/ssl/certs/cacert.pem as described in the post Tensibal indicated and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: That is not recommended and will be undone the next time you upgrade chefdk.

Comment: Sure, I understand. I hope there will be update on this on next versions.